# How to enforce div minimum size with jQueryUI resize - without allowing panel to move?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, resizable

I am working on an extension of the [presentation tool](http://code.google.com/p/go.talks/present/) for the Go language (this is not a Go question) demonstrated [here](http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1).

Currently when a runnable code snippet is run in a presentation a fixed sized output panel is displayed, for example [here](http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#12) (You can click the 'Run' button at that page to run the Go code in the snippet - executed server-side). I have a change list that allows jquery-ui to resize the panel from the N, W and NW handles. That's all good. Here is the relevant code and CSS that does that:

play.js (snippet):

```js
  function init(code) {
    var id = getId();

    var output = document.createElement('div');
    var outpre = document.createElement('pre');
    var stopFunc;

    $(output).resizable({handles: "n,w,nw"});

    function onKill() {
      if (stopFunc) {
        stopFunc();
      }
    }

    function onRun() {
      onKill();
      outpre.innerHTML = "";
      output.style.display = "block";

    ... more
```

styles.css (snippet):

```css
/* Code */
div.code {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}
div.playground {
  position: relative;
}
div.output {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  background: #202020;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  z-index: 2;

  border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

}
div.output pre {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.output .stdout, div.output pre {
  color: #e6e6e6;
}
div.output .stderr, div.output .error {
  color: rgb(244, 74, 63);
}
div.output .system, div.output .exit {
  color: rgb(255, 209, 77)
}
.buttons {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: -60px;
  right: 10px;
}
div.output .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  float: none;
  top: auto;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

/* Output resize details */
.ui-resizable-handle {
  position: absolute;
}
.ui-resizable-n {
  cursor: n-resize;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
}
.ui-resizable-w {
  cursor: w-resize;
  width: 7px;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.ui-resizable-nw {
  cursor: nw-resize;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

This does nearly all that I want except for one problem: I want to specify a minimum size for the output panel so that the control buttons are always surrounded by the panel. I can achieve this with the min-height and min-width CSS attributes in div.output, except that these attributes enforce the minimum by moving the bottom/right edges of the panel.

How can I specify a minimum height and width while keeping the bottom and right edges positioned at their original locations?

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative absolute positioning for your buttons. So, you would set the min-height for the `<pre>` tag 36px less than that of the output box. Then, position the button's div to wherever you want within the output div.

> div.output { 
>     position: relative;
>   }
>
> div.buttons {
>   position:absolute;
>   bottom: 0;
>   right: 150px;
>   }

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how that helps. I'm trying to retain the bottom and right positions at 40px even when resize tries to make the size smaller than the specified minimum height/width.